# Revert master to old commit while preserving commits

Tags: git, github, git-revert

This is what my commit history looks like (everything has been pushed to Github where my repo is stored, but I'm the only contributor):

```
                           master       
                             |
..-c100-c101-c102-c103-...-c150
```

I need to revert `master` to the `c100` commit while *keeping* the remaining commits (ie: `c101-c102...-c150`), I don't want to loose them.

So this is what I came up with:

```
git checkout -b new-branch # Set up branch containing all commits
git checkout master        # Go back to master
git revert <c-100>         # Revert master branch to c-100 commit
```

which would (hopefully) result in:

```
   master
     |
..-c100-c101-c102-c103-...-c150
                             |
                        new-branch
```

Ideally I would then make a few commits to master to then leave it untouched until I can merge the new branch into it.

Is this the correct way to do this?

---

**Add**

Well just tried it and using `git revert <SHA>` does not work, it only reverts *that* commit.

Comment: git revert != snv revert.  It sounds like you need to do `git reset --hard c100` followed by a force push.  There are a lot of other threads on SO about this

Comment: I just tried the commands in my question and it didn't work, it only reverted _that_ commit, it didn't put `master` back to the state it was on that commit. So I guess you are right.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal. You could also just set a tag on the tip of the commit you want to commit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718540/1391441)) to use:

```
git revert --no-commit c-100..HEAD
git commit
```